# Save form fields to a user specified file using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to save the value of a text-area to the file name that in other text box. 
EX:-

```
<form name="Form" method="post" action="" enctype="text/plain" id="Form">
  <input type="text" id="filename"  name="filename" value="saved.txt">
  <textarea name="text-area" id="text-area" rows="8" cols="77">This is the Text Area
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Please help me on this problem. I want the PHP code to enter on top and action at the form.

Comment: You want the PHP code but what PHP code have you tried so far ?

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I checked <?php 
$fn = "textfile.txt"; 
$file = fopen($fn, "w+"); 
$size = filesize($fn); 

if($_POST['update']) fwrite($file, $_POST['update']); 

//$text = fread($file, $size); 
fclose($file); 
?> But, It couldn't give the value in textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Value of text-area using jquery and fill it to your desire field.

```js
$("#filename").val($("#text-area").val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="Form" method="post" action="" enctype="text/plain" id="Form">
  <input type="text" id="filename"  name="filename" value="saved.txt">
  <textarea name="text-area" id="text-area" rows="8" cols="77">This is the Text Area
  </textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: What should be added action="" in form?

Comment: whatever as per your requirement. it does not matter.

Comment: Please explain me some more things. I don't understand what to do. Please help me! I am a newbie to PHP

Comment: Oh! Sorry! the file should be saved inside the computer, not at ftp server    The custom error module does not recognize this error.

Comment: is it helpful ?

Comment: Yes! it is help full! Thanks!